# Selenium Python - Extract Text from Class

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to extract the text from the second "deep" class in the following image. In this case it would be the word "Sauvage"

[The Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uHwF.png)

I've done the following:

```
search_perfumes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="deep"][1]')
for perfumes in search_perfumes:
    list_perfumes.append(perfumes.text)
```

The length of the list correctly shows 23 elements (which is correct since the page has 23 perfumes), but the list has 23 empty elements. I can't seem to extract the text following the  "deep" class.

Any idea on where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `Html` that you've shared, you can use XPath indexing:

```
(//span[@class='deep'])[2]
```

in code:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='deep'])[2]"))).text)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Now you must ensure that `[2]` represent `Sauvage` in the entire HTML. You can **increase or decrease indices** from `[2]` to any other matching number.

How would you do that? - You need to make sure that we have a unique matching node in HTMLDOM. Please see below for more detailed explanation:

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

Also, you can have a list of web elements with this xpath `//span[@class='deep']`

```
for ele in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='deep']"):
    print(ele.text)
```

**Update:**

You have to **click** on `Accept all` cookie button first which is in **shadow root:**

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.parfumdreams.pt/?m=5&search=sauvage")

try:
    time.sleep(2)
    cookie_btn = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#usercentrics-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("#uc-center-container > div.sc-jJoQJp.dTzACB > div > div > div > button")')
    cookie_btn.click()
    print('Clicked')
except:
    print('Could not click')
    pass


print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//span[@class='deep'])[2]"))).text)
```

or in case you want all of them, instead of the above print command, use the below code:

```
for ele in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='deep']"):
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
    print(ele.text)
```

**Output:**

```
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
Creed
Neroli Sauvage
DIOR
Eau Sauvage
DIOR
Lápis de lábios
DIOR
Lápis de lábios
Estée Lauder
Maquilhagem para lábios
```

Comment: Didn't know I could that to check if the it is the correct element. That's really helpful!

Although i'm now getting the following error message: 
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Is it possible to share the page URL?

Comment: https://www.parfumdreams.pt/?m=5&search=sauvage

Comment: @Foxy: See the above updated section.

Comment: I see what happened. Since I'm adding the user data directory folder to chrome options I have to run the program without headless at least once to accept the cookies. I totally forgot about it! Thank you! It was working all along after all.

Comment: The convention in SO is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer. Since we have two answers, you should choose the best answer which addresses your issue for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to extract text from second **web element** matching `//span[@class="deep"]` XPath.
You are possibly missing a wait, trying to extract the text before the element completely loaded. I'm not sure about that since you don't share all you code.
Please try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//span[@class="deep"][2]')))
search_perfumes = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[@class="deep"][2]')
for perfumes in search_perfumes:
    list_perfumes.append(perfumes.text)
```

Comment: Tried it but it gives me the following message error:

selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: OK, I see. I have updated the answer. Now it will work correctly

Comment: Possibly this will not give you all the 23 texts, but at least part of them it will give you. In case not all the text will be extracted you will need to add scrolling

Comment: I see what happened. Since I'm adding the user data directory folder to chrome options I have to run the program without headless at least once to accept the cookies. I totally forgot about it! Thank you! It was working all along after all.

Comment: you can run in headless mode as well. You are possibly missing setting the window size for the headless more. Without that your default headless screen size it too small...